# Number of trials rolling six 6-sided dice to get 6 unique values

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

I have six 6-sided dice, and I want to roll them until I have all six distinct values (assume them to be naturals 1-6), in no particular order.

The naive strategy would be to roll all 6 dice until I have all 6 values. The expected number of trials until success is $\frac{6^6}{6!} = 64.8$.

A smarter strategy would be to roll a die until its value is distinct from the values of other dice already rolled. Eg. the first die gets rolled once, its value is 3, and then I roll the second one until its value is something else than 3, say 4. Then I roll the 3rd one until its value is neither 3 nor 4, etc. This way, the expected number of trials is $\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{6}{i} = 14.7$.

An even smarter strategy would be to first roll all 6 dice, then pick the *duplicates* ‒ all except one ‒ and roll these again. Repeat untill I have all 6 values. For example:

- first roll: 1 1 2 4 4 4 (the order doesn't matter)
- pick 1 4 4, leave 1 2 4 on the table
- roll the 3 dice (which had values 1 4 4) again
- repeat this until there are values 1-6 on the table

Question: what is the expected number of trials with this strategy?

Comment: **Basic approach.** Denote by $t_k, 1 \leq k \leq 6$ the expected number of further rolls required to get six distinct numbers when there are currently $k$ distinct numbers.  So $t_6 = 0$.  We can write $t_5 = 1 + \frac56 t_5 + \frac16 t_6$, which gives us $\frac16 t_5 = 1$, or $t_5 = 6$.  We can similarly write $t_4 = 1 + p_{44} t_4 + p_{45} t_5 + p_{46} t_6$, with $p_{ij}$ representing the usual transition probabilities, and derive $t_4$.  We work our way down to $t_1$.  Then we simply figure out how many distinct numbers we get on the first roll, and weight the $t_k$ accordingly.

Comment: P.S.  That last step can be thought of as deriving $t_0$ in the same way...

Comment: Nice. It didn't occur to me to take it from the other end. Any ideas for a closed-form solution?

Comment: For the general case?  I'm not sure, I haven't given it much thought.  This seems like it must be something that's been looked at before.  For the particular case of six six-sided dice, it's simple enough (if a bit tedious) to work it out by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I outlined in a comment, we denote by $t_k, 1 \leq k \leq 6$, the expected number of further rolls required to get six distinct numbers when there are currently $k$ distinct numbers.  So, for example, $t_6 = 0$, because there are already six distinct numbers.

If there are currently $k = 5$ distinct numbers, we pick up the duplicate and reroll it.  There are two possibilities:

- The reroll is also a duplicate, with probability $\frac56$.
- The reroll is the last unrolled number, with probability $\frac16$.

This allows us to write the recurrence

$$
t_5 = 1 + \frac56 t_5
$$

which can be solved to yield $t_5 = 6$.  If there are $k = 4$ distinct numbers, we pick up the two duplicates and reroll them.  There are *four* possibilities:

- Both rerolls are still duplicates, with probability $\left(\frac23\right)^2 = \frac49$.
- One reroll is a duplicate, but the other is a new number, with probability $2\left(\frac23\right)\left(\frac13\right) = \frac49$.
- Both rerolls are the same new number, with probability $2\left(\frac16\right)^2 = \frac{1}{18}$.
- The rerolls are the last two numbers, also with probability $2\left(\frac16\right)^2 = \frac{1}{18}$.

The second and third cases both yield five distinct numbers, so we can write the recurrence

$$
t_4 = 1 + \frac49 t_4 + \left(\frac49+\frac{1}{18}\right) t_5
$$

Plugging in $t_5 = 6$ reduces this to

$$
t_4 = 4 + \frac49 t_4
$$

which yields $t_4 = \frac{36}{5}$.  In general, we may write

$$
t_k = 1 + \sum_{j=k}^5 p_{kj} t_j
$$

where $p_{kj}$ is the probability of going from $k$ distinct numbers to $j \geq k$ distinct numbers in a single roll.  There's probably an explicit summation form for this, but I'm afraid I'm too lazy to think of it at the present time.  At any rate, we can continue along in the same vein to write

\begin{align}
t_3 & = 1 + \frac18 t_3 + \frac{37}{72} t_4 + \frac13 t_5 \\
    & = 1 + \frac18 t_3 + \frac{37}{10} + 2 \\
    & = \frac{67}{10} + \frac18 t_3
\end{align}

yielding $t_3 = \frac{268}{35}$, then

\begin{align}
t_2 & = 1 + \frac{1}{81} t_2 + \frac{65}{324} t_3
          + \frac{55}{108} t_4 + \frac{7}{27} t_5 \\
    & = 1 + \frac{1}{81} t_2 + \frac{871}{567} + \frac{11}{3} + \frac{14}{9} \\
    & = \frac{4399}{567} + \frac{1}{81} t_2
\end{align}

yielding $t_2 = \frac{4399}{560}$, then

\begin{align}
t_1 & = 1 + \frac{1}{7776} t_1 + \frac{155}{7776} t_2 + \frac{25}{108} t_3
          + \frac{325}{648} t_4 + \frac{25}{108} t_5 \\
    & = 1 + \frac{1}{7776} t_1 + \frac{136369}{870912} + \frac{335}{189}
          + \frac{65}{18} + \frac{25}{18} \\
    & = \frac{986503}{124416} + \frac{1}{7776} t_1
\end{align}

yielding $t_1 = \frac{986503}{124400}$.  (Thanks to @user in the comments for noticing an error in my original computation!)  Finally, we observe that if $k = 1$ (that is, if you only have one distinct number), you're essentially right where you started, so the overall expected number of rolls until you get six distinct numbers is

$$
t = t_1 = \frac{986503}{124400} \approx 7.93009
$$

There may be a simpler and cleverer way to this answer.

Comment: +1 Love the observation that $t_0 = t_1$ !!  It took me a few minutes to convince myself this is because $p_{0k} = p_{1k}$ for any $k \ge 1$ so the RHS of the respective recurrences for $t_0$ and $t_1$ are identical.  Do you have a more intuitive way to explain this?

Comment: As a side note, if you count each roll of a die as a single trial (eg. the fist roll of all 6 dice counts as 6 trials), then the expected number of trials is $14.7$ (basically doing the second strategy, but in parallel).

Comment: @kyrill: Right, that's essentially the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) with $n = 6$ choices.

Comment: @antkam: None, other than that if you actually are "unlucky" enough to roll six of a kind on the first roll, you might as well just roll all of them all over.

Comment: I believe there is an error in the end of your calculation. It should be $$t_1=\frac{986503}{124416}+\frac1{7776}t_1.$$ Correspondingly $$t_1=\frac{986503}{124400}\approx7.93009.$$

Comment: @user Now I see why my experimental results were a bit off... Well done!

Comment: @user: There sure is.  I must have fat-fingered something in the computation.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @user: Thanks again for the edit!

Answer (score 2):

As a back-of-the-envelope calculation, I expect around $$\frac{\pi^2}6n$$ rolls are needed.
Most rolls are spent tidying up the final few numbers.
It takes $n$ rolls to get the final number.
With two numbers to go, success is four times as likely, as two dice each have two successful rolls, so around $n/4$ rolls are needed to advance.  With three to go, around $n/9$ are needed.  The chance of advancing more than one step at a time is relatively small.  So my leading-order estimate is $n+(n/4)+(n/9)+...$ which is the number at the top of this answer.
EDIT  A better fit seems to be
$$\frac{\pi^2}6n-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-0.75$$
I got the first correction from a more precise version of the argument above, but the $0.75$ is taken from simulations, a million trials at each of $n=2$ to $20$.
The following graph shows the difference between the average and $\pi^2n/6$.  One curve is simulations, the other curve is from the formula above.
[image]

EDIT: I want to record where the first correction term comes from.
I change variables, so that $s_k=t_{n-k}$, and $k$ is the number of dice being rolled.  Following the accepted answer,  out of $n^k$ possible rolls, most roll no new numbers; sometimes one of the $k$ dice rolls one of $k$ new numbers; or two roll the same new number; or two roll different new numbers.  The rest will be $O(n^{k-3})s_k$, and negligible for this calculation.
$$n^k s_k=n^k+(n-k)^k s_k + \\
k^2 (n-k)^{k-1} s_{k-1} + \\
{k\choose2} k (n-k)^{k-2} s_{k-1} + \\
{k\choose2} (k^2-k) (n-k)^{k-2}s_{k-2}+...$$
To leading order, $k^2s_k=n+k^2s_{k-1}$, which leads to the $n\pi^2/6$.
Now bring in the next order, let $s_k=n×a_k+b_k$.  We know $a_k=\sum^k_{i=1}(1/i^2)$.  The $b_{k-2}$ term is negligible, but by combining the known $a_{k-1}$ and $a_{k-2}$, it simplifies to $b_k=b_{k-1}-1/(2k)$

Comment: What do the lines in the graph represent?

Comment: Your question was about six six-sided dice.  The graphs are about $n$ $n$-sided dice.   The x-axis is $n$.  To show the expected number of trials $E(n) = npi^2/6 - f(n)$, I have plotted the simulated $E(n) - npi^2/6$ and the exact formula $-f(n)$ on the same graph.

Comment: I wonder if your $0.75$ is actually somehow related to the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), like maybe the result is actually something like $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\ln n}{2}-1$.