# $n$ balls into $n$ urns until there is no empty urn.

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value, conditional-expectation, balls-in-bins

We have $n$ balls and $n$ urns.

**Step 1**. Throw $n$ balls into $n$ urns randomly.

Check each urn and if there is more than one ball in an urn, choose only one and keep in the urn and remove all the other balls.

**Step 2.** Suppose there are $k$ balls ''not placed'' in an urn in Step 1. Throw these $k$ balls into the urns randomly.

And move on in this fashion until there is no empty urn.

*What is the expected number of urns that are empty in each step?*

**Answer.** Step 1 is easy. For any urn $u_{j}$, define $X_{j}$ as $X_{j}=1$ if no ball hits and $X_{j}=0$, otherwise. Then, expected number of empty urns is just $E(X)$ where $X=X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{n}$. Note that $E(X_{j})=Pr(X_{j}=1)=(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$. Hence, $E(X)=n(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$.

After Step 1, things get complicated. A heuristic approach for Step 2: The expected number of empty urns (and hence unplaced balls) is just $n(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$. Thus, for large $n$, the expected number of empty urns in Step 2 is $n\left( \frac{n-1}{n}\right) ^{n}\left( \frac{n-1}{n}\right) ^{n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) ^{n}}$ (within some bound?)

Is this approach correct? Can this be made rigorous?

Comment: You may have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349773/sequential-allocation-of-n-balls-into-n-urns?rq=1

Does this answer/help with your question?

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445958/number-of-trials-rolling-six-6-sided-dice-to-get-6-unique-values I suggest the average number of steps needed is roughly $n\pi^2/6-\frac12\ln n$

Answer (score 1):

Let label the states with the number of the filled urns. Our aim is to find the probability of transition from the state $m$ to the state $l$ ($0\le m\le l\le n$). This probability is:
$$\begin{align}
P_{ml}(n)&=\frac1{n^{n-m}}\binom{n-m}{l-m}
\sum_{i=l-m}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}i(l-m)!{i \brace l-m}m^{n-m-i}\\
&=\frac1{n^{n-m}}\frac{(n-m)!}{(n-l)!}
\sum_{i=l-m}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}i{i \brace l-m}m^{n-m-i},\tag1
\end{align}$$
where the symbols count the following numbers of way:

1. $n^{n-m}$ - to place $n-m$ balls into $n$ urns;
2. $\binom{n-m}{l-m}$ - to choose $l-m$ "active" urns to be filled out of $n-m$ empty ones;
3. $\binom{n-m}i$ - to choose $i$ balls out of $n-m$ ones;
4. $(l-m)!{i \brace l-m}$ - to place $i$ balls into $l-m$ "active" urns in such a way that there is at least one ball in each of these urns. Here  ${i \brace l-m}$ is the Stirling number of second kind;
5. $m^{n-m-i}$ - to place the rest balls into $m$ already filled urns.

After the transition matrix $P(n)$ is constructed the expected value of the empty urns after $k$ steps can be computed as:
$$
\mathsf E_k(n)=n-\sum_{i=1}^n i[P^k(n)]_{0i}.\tag2
$$

---

**Example.**

For $n=5$ one obtains:

$$P(5)=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 0 & \frac{1}{625} & \frac{12}{125} & \frac{12}{25} & \frac{48}{125} & \frac{24}{625} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{625} & \frac{12}{125} & \frac{12}{25} & \frac{48}{125} & \frac{24}{625} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{8}{125} & \frac{57}{125} & \frac{54}{125} & \frac{6}{125} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{9}{25} & \frac{14}{25} & \frac{2}{25} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{array}\right).$$

The corresponding values $\mathsf E_k (5)$ for $k=1,\dots,10$ are respectively:
$$
\begin{array}{l} 1.6384 \\ 1.07168 \\ 0.782347 \\ 0.599572 \\ 0.470231 \\ 0.372795 \\ 0.297015 \\ 0.237173 \\ 0.18958 \\ 0.151607 \\\end{array}
$$

---

One can easily demonstrate that the 0th and the 1st rows of the transition matrix are identical, and the 0th column is $0$. Therefore one can for the sake of simplicity drop the 0th row and column from the matrix, so that $1\le m,l\le n$ in (1). The only required change after the redefinition of $P(n)$ is to replace the index $0i $ in the formula (2) with $1i $.